How to display a watermark QLabel on top of QVideoWidget in PyQt6?
I'm trying to create a video player in PyQt6 that displays a watermark (QLabel) on top of the video. However, my watermark label goes behind the video when I run the code. I've tried using raise_() to bring the label to the front, but it didn't work.
Here's my initial code:
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QUrl
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QFrame, QLabel
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        video_path = 'path\\to\\myvideo.mp4'
        wm_path = 'path\\to\\myimage.png'
        MainWindow.resize(500, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 300))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(parent=self.frame)
        self.videoWidget = QVideoWidget(parent=self.frame)
        self.videoWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 200, 150))

        self.wmLabel = QLabel(parent=self.frame)
        self.wmLabel.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 100, 100))

        pixmap = QPixmap(wm_path)
        self.wmLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.wmLabel.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.wmLabel.raise_()

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(video_path))
        self.mediaPlayer.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

I've tried setting the wmLabel's parent to self.videoWidget and using raise_(), but the label still appears behind the video. How can I ensure that the watermark label stays on top of the video?
I found this two links but that work for PyQt5 and not for PyQt6
Display widget on top of QVideoWidget with QMediaPlayer
How to draw QtGraphicsView on Top of QVideoWidget with transparency

Use QGraphicsVideoItem in a QGraphicsView.

Thank you for your comment, @musicamante ! Can you explain more? I don't know how to use QGraphicsVideoItem and QGraphicsView :(

If you haven't used QGraphicsView and associated classes before then please read the documentation.  Note that the second link in your question already tells you precisely how to do this.

Does this answer your question? How to draw QtGraphicsView on Top of QVideoWidget with transparency

Migrating from PyQt5 to PyQt6 is straightforward. See this.
